# seeing images after logout

Tags: cypress

When I run Cypress (9.6.1) in interactive mode (with `npx cypress open`) at first my tests look fine. But after running through, when I click on specific test steps, I cannot see any images of my website. However, when I remove my logout code from `after()`, I do see all the images.

Is there any good solution for this? Or do people just never logout in Cypress test code?

Comment: Is there a reason for logging out? Are you testing something that happens after logout?

Comment: Well, no. I do not test anything after logout. It just seems to make sense to me to clean up after work is done. After all, I don't leave database connections open after tests, etc.

Comment: Also I can share authentications between tests in one file (using `session`), but not between test files, it seems. So I guess multiple authentications of the test account would accumulate at the auth server.

Comment: Using the after() hook for cleaning up is an anti-pattern in cypress. The beauty of cypress is further developing and debugging after the tests ran. Because of the asyncronous behaviour of cypress there is no gurantee anyways that the cleanup in the after() runs. Instead try to set up your tests properly in the before/beforeEach hooks. Read more about this [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#It-s-all-downside-with-no-upside)

Comment: OK, now I removed the logout. Thanks.